# Do Indian YouTubers need to register for GST?

Tags: income-tax, india, gst

If an Indian professional earns 30 lakh per annum from his regular job and then 18 lakhs per annum from YouTube and Affiliate Marketing, do they need to register for GST?
The personal also earns 4 lakhs from Savings Interest / FDs / Investments.

GST requirements are required on amount greater than 20 lakh annual, but does this include incomes from other sources as well?

[This post](https://taxguru.in/goods-and-service-tax/interest-income-included-aggregate-turnover-gst-registration.html) suggests that even if your side income was < 20 lakhs but if you include savings interest / FDs and your annual revenue exceeds 20 lakhs, then yes, you should register for GST.

Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

Best consult a CA who can advise as well as defend if there are any enquiries.

As per the interpretation GST registration is not required, however there seems to be a ruling... maybe be a slightly different case.